# pygame on MacOs won't show any surfaces

Tags: python, pygame, surface

I'm following a very basic pygame tutorial, which I've done before. I'm suspecting there's a version issue, though I'm at a loss how to move forward.

```
macOS 10.14.4
Python 3.7.2
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

surf = pygame.Surface((75,25))
surf.fill((125,125,125))
# What does this rect do?
rect = surf.get_rect()

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.blit(surf, (400,300))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The only question I have there is what is that rect assignment for? I can't blit the rect, so it appears to have no purpose.

I've gone through a couple other tutorials, copy-pasted code and I get the same result with each one: a white screen with no rectangles. It's as if the display code works, but any other surface just don't appear.

[image: empty pygame display]

No errors in the console. I'm really not sure how to debug at this point.

Comment: You're right, the `rect = surf.get_rect()` is useless since the `rect` isn't used in any of the following code. AFAIK you're seeing the corrected output given that nothing is changing the surface `surf`. Perhaps this code is just the beginnings of a more advanced/involved code that will be discussed and added later on in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to debug here. `rect = surf.get_rect()` is not used, maybe like martineau said in the comment will be used later in the tutorial.

What the code is doing is to draw a small gray rectangle on a gray surface (that's why you do not see anything).

```
surf = pygame.Surface((75,25))
```

This creates a small gray surface, which is blit later in the main loop at coordinates (top-left corner) 400, 300:

```
screen.blit(surf, (400,300))
```

As I said, the reason you do not see it is because `surf` il filled with gray (this line):

```
surf.fill((125,125,125))
```

and your background is gray too. I do not know if this is system dependent, on my linux the background is black and the rectangle is clearly visible.

[image: screenshot]

So try to change the color of the rectangle to something clearer or darker, or fill the display surface with black before the main loop by doing:

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: The thing is, I've tried a number of colors for small rectangle surface: (0,255,0) was the last, but I've tried a bunch. Your idea to color the screen is a good suggestion, but it has no effect on the screen either. Seeing it on your screen makes me think this is a macOS issue, I just have no idea how to trouble-shoot

Comment: Mh, yes, is possible. Have a look here, maybe is helpful: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555